# Can't get value from application.yml when using @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I want to use @ConfigurationProperties to get value(secretName and region) from application.yml, but the result keep showing null, I have no idea why I can't get the value, can anyone help me with that? Thanks

```
aws-secretManager:
    secretName: "test-mvp"
    region: "us-west-2"
```

```
@ConstructorBinding
@Component

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws-secretManager")

data class MyInfoDataClass(
    var secretName: String = "",
    var region: String = "",
)


class GetSecretConfig {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetSecretConfig::class.java)

    data class SecretDataClass(val user: String)
    data class SecretInfoDataClass(val username: String, val password: String)

    @Bean
    fun getSecret(myInfoDataClass: MyInfoDataClass): SecretInfoDataClass {
        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        val client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(myInfoDataClass.region).build()
        val getSecretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(myInfoDataClass.secretName)

        var getSecretValueResult: GetSecretValueResult = 
            client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest)
         
        val responseString = SecretDataClass(getSecretValueResult.secretString).user
        val username = JSONObject(responseString).get("username").toString()
        val password = JSONObject(responseString).get("password").toString()
        return SecretInfoDataClass(username, password)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use camel case in application.yml/properties file. Use dashes instead to separate words:

```yaml
aws-secret-manager:
    secret-name: "test-mvp"
    region: "us-west-2"
```

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws-secret-manager")
data class MyInfoDataClass(
    var secretName: String = "",
    var region: String = "",
)
```